# Writing implementation of child class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I ran into a bit of a roadblock when writing a child class' constructor..

In my program I have an `entity` class which describes a generic object in the game. It has members that everything will have, such as position, sprite image, an object name, etc.

There is a child class called `creature` that inherits from `entity`, describing any kind of living object/thing in the game, the player, monster, what have you.

`entity.h` has the constructor:

`entity(int a, int b, int c, string n, char d)`, explicity creating an entity at `(a,b,c)` with name `n` and display character `d`.

`creature` inherits `entity`, and the aforementioned constructor. Although it has several other things that need to be initialized, namely the creature's stats that takes its own code block to describe.

.:., `creature.h` has the constructor:

`creature(int a, int b, int c, string n, char d) : entity(a,b,c,n,d) { }`

However, when I go to write `creature.cpp`, and write the implementation for this constructor to initialize the stats, I cannot get passed a "redefinition" / "previously defined" error. My first guess was to remove the brackets at the end but then I get `"expected { at end of input"`. The only temporary solution I found was to write the implementation in the { } of the `creature.h` file, but that's not the practice I want to observe here of course.

What is the correct syntax to do this? The only examples I could find from digging around write the definition and implementation in the same set of code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class declaration for `creature`, just put this:

```
creature(int a, int b, int c, string n, char d);
```

Then in your `creature.cpp`, put the full thing:

```
creature::creature(int a, int b, int c, string n, char d) : entity(a,b,c,n,d) 
{ 
    // body of the constructor
}
```

Comment: Hm I was sure I tried that! Let me try again. (I think finals may have gotten the best of me)

Update: D'oh, well, that did it. Thanks a lot!